# how to rearrange tags in a widget in AEM?

Tags: adobe, aem

How can we re-arrange tags in a widget in  AEM?
For example, I have selected multiple tags, and I want to move tags up or down based on the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, tagfield do not allow sequencing (not sure if latest version support this much needed feature), so i prefer to use multifeld and each multifield has one path selector to select tag. 
PS. Multifield provide ordering feature.